# Custom Commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there anyway to make custom commands in 1.7.10 vanilla minecraft? I have tried to use the /testfor command as suggested in other websites but this does not work. Is this possible?

Comment: In short, no. Minecraft does not support any custom commands in form of /mycustomcommand without server plugins or mods. You can do things like /trigger but that is not what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: `/trigger` is likely close to what you want, but was only added in 1.8.

Comment: What does /trigger do?

Comment: I have to ask, why are you using 1.7 if you're sticking to vanilla?  Also, `testfor` is mostly useless, especially pre-1.9 versions.  Whichever websites that are suggesting you use it are websites that I'd ignore.

Comment: I'm using 1.7 because I'm working on my friends server and since they haven't made essentials for 1.8 I'm still on 1.7

Comment: @gamer103: See, that's information that's potentially useful.  When you say you're using vanilla Minecraft, there's no consideration from us given to server plugins.